# prestashop not changing base url

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have an installation of prestashop 1.6 on a domain www.mydomain.com and a virtualhost on a server for redirecting to the prestashop/public_html folder. This is my main website working perfect.

Now i would like to clone the installation in another folder prestashop/clone_html and i created an alias on the virtualhost from www.mydomain.com/clone to prestashop/clone_html

Now if i access the clone website the frontend is not working, i get a 404 error and all the links are pointing on the main domain

I tried to change settings.inc.php change the base URI on the database and delete both .htaccess and cache but the links are never changing.

I think maybe the problem is coming from multilanguage redirect?
Do you have any idea what i should try to change?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply use a subdomain?

Comment: you mean putting the other installation in another folder without alias? Because i'm used to use Larvel and i presumed also prestashop rewrites all the url in the subdomain

Comment: I mean having both installations in different folders, then have your main instal on your main domain, and have the clone on a subdomain in your vhost. You then simply have to change the URL of the clone in the DB in table `ps_configuration`, look for the 2 fields with the URL in them.

Comment: Even if you move shop to a new domain, you can still access your backend at www.newdomain.com/youradminfolder and make changes to the shop URL from backend.

Answer (score 2):

That is a good one! If you want to change the URL of the store and you have already migrated the contents (so no access to the admin is possible or you don´t want to bother), you may do the change directly at the PS table where this information is kept. The name of the table is `<prefix>shop_url`. Once you access it, the content is self explanatory. You have to play with `domain` or `domain_ssl` and then with `physical_uri`.

Also, using a subdomain as has been suggested in a comment may be a good idea. Depending on your hosting, you may be able to define a subdomain and make it point to a subdirectory. This keeps the `physical_uri` to `/` and may avoid other potential problems.

Comment: And how about the url's in <prefix>configuration

Comment: Yes, you should check any entries at `<prefix>configuration` that contain your domain name. When I migrate a shop I check this table too. Certain modules may rely on variables defined here.